# js code and svg path is not working in browser

Tags: html, svg, raphael

This is my fiddle which is perfectly running http://jsfiddle.net/demo_Ashif/tmQ2H/

```
//
var rsrGroups = [Dist1,Dist2];

for (var i = 0, len = rsrGroups.length; i <= len; i++) {

    var el = rsrGroups[i];

    el.mouseover(function() {
        this.toFront();
        this.attr({
            cursor: 'pointer',
            fill: '#990000',
            stroke: '#fff',
            'stroke-width': '2'
        });
        this.animate({
            scale: '1.2'
        }, 200);
    });
    el.mouseout(function() {
        this.animate({
            scale: '1.05'
        }, 200);
        this.attr({
            fill: '#003366'
        });
    });
    el.click(function() {
        this.animate({
            fill: 'green'
        }, 200);
    });

}
//
```

But same code is not running in my `index.html` page. same in Chrome and Firefox. I am not understanding the fault. please someone solve it.

Comment: Describe the expected behavior, describe the behavior you're seeing. Ask an specific question.

Comment: my scenerio will be that, on mouseover event i will show some text about that map area like http://raphaeljs.com/australia.html . but after editing html and etc in 'text editor' nothing is happening. only blank page. before completeting full work i just wanted to check that svg paths and raphael hover animation is ok or not. its ok on jsfiddle (given link) but not when i am opening as html page in my browser.

Comment: are you receiving any javascript errors?

Comment: Check console for errors as mentioned. Check you are loading in Raphael first correctly, and have the div there.

Comment: @zgood and lan thanks for your co-operation. Now it is fixed though little differently. And there was an error in raphael.js file. may be there was flaw when i copied the library file.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a very old version of RaphaelJS -- 1.5.2 -- in your fiddle. You should be using 2.1.0, which you probably are in the browser, hence the error.

The problem is that `Dist1` and `Dist2` are sets, not elements, which don't directly take events. But there's no need to do this since you only have one item per set. Just assign the variables directly to the `path` objects:

```
var Dist1 = rsr.path("m 184.17891,318.14557...")
var Dist2 = rsr.path("m 352.66606,280.9633...")
```

A few other errors:

- The arguments to `Raphael` are reversed: Should be `var rsr = Raphael('rsr', 0, 0, 612, 792)`, with `x` and `y` and then `width` and `length`
- Your `for` loop is starting at index 2 for a zero-indexed two-item array. In any event, it would be better to use `rsrGroups.forEach(function(el) {...`

In Raphael 2.1.0, you can't directly animate the scale. Simple fix:

```
this.animate({
    transform: "s1.2"
}, 200);
```

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raphaeljs/sf9c3pby/4/), but please take a moment to see what I did -- I commented out your code where it was breaking.

(I wrote the [O'Reilly book on RaphaelJS](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/raphaeljs/9781449365356/) if you plan to keep using it, and assure you that any royalties at this point are negligible, so I'm not out to make any money here!)